# Reactjs web application with database?

Tags: mysql, database, reactjs, web-applications

How can I connect my `ReactJS` Web application with a database like `MySQL`, in `PHP` you can configure it in the configuration file. Is there any way to do this in React, or should I set up an API server as per the following link

[building-dynamic-react-apps-with-database-data](https://dzone.com/articles/building-dynamic-react-apps-with-database-data)

or should I do this as per the recommendation from this link

[Learn Express then move to React](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-Database-to-implement-in-a-ReactJS-project-I-want-to-use-MySQL-but-cant-find-a-tutorial-on-how-to-use-it-with-ReactJS-Pls-advice)

where a person recommended to do this in the following quote

**"ReactJS is just the view in MVC. You will want to look at Express a web framework for Node.js. I found Getting Started with Node.js + MySQL | Codementor  and there seems to be many more tutorials if you search "express mysql".
After you have learnt Express you can move onto using it with ReactJS.
Also if you know MySQL, that normally that means you know PHP and a PHP framework. For Laravel there is a tutorial by Laracasts Do You React?. I am sure other PHP frameworks will also have tutorials on it."**

Comment: Indeed, React does not query the database directly. You need something (like PHP) to provide an API for React to consume.

Comment: Thanks, I initially thought so, but I read somewhere that u can do it, I have edited the question with more details.

Comment: The backend could be Node+Express, or PHP, or Python, Rails, or whatever you prefer, React is truly agnostic in that regard. It's really up to you. Another bleeding edge avenue you could explore to provide data to your React frontend is GraphQL (I would recommend Apollo over Relay, at least for starters).

Comment: Okay Thanks for the info